# css is not getting applied in rails 4.2.5.1?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

"I'm generating controller in rails it generates css for me but when i add css in assets/stylesheets controller_name.scss.css it doesn't gets included but when i add it itself in html file it gets there."

"This is my controller_name.scss.css file"

```
// Place all the styles related to the boo controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
h1 { color:#77eeff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;}
```

and this is application.css

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over    styles    defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the "controller_name.scss.css" file to "controller_name.css.scss" the preprocessor extension should be chained at the end as far as I remember. Also, if your application environment is "production" then you must run:

`bundle exec production rake assets:precompile`

If it is development then just run:

`rake assets:precompile`

Take a look at the rails guide about the asset pipeline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: still not working when i run rake assets:precompile it says `rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: Could you please run `rake assets:precompile --trace` and comment the output here?